# Why can't I assign the updated value to variable 'word' here in the for-of loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Why can't I update the array 'words' using this for-of loop?

```
function capitalizeLetters(str) {
    let words = str.split(' ');

    for(var word of words)
        word = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

    return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalizeLetters('i love javascript'));
```

Comment: The value of `word` does change, but that doesn't change the array.

Comment: Why? because word is a variable with same value as in the array...but not a reference to the element in the array

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: By revising the array element with the new value

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to `word`, but since it's a primitive, and not a pointer to a place in the area, the value is replaced, but it doesn't update the array. You can use `Array.map()` instead:

```js
function capitalizeLetters(str) {
  return str.split(' ')
    .map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalizeLetters('i love javascript'));
```

Another option is to use `String.replace()` with capture groups for the 1st letter (head) and the rest of the letters (tail) in the word. Then change the case, and combine them again with a string literal:

```js
function capitalizeLetters(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\w)(\w+)/g, 
    (_, head, tail) => `${head.toUpperCase()}${tail.toLowerCase()}`
  );
}

console.log(capitalizeLetters('i love javascript'));
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the value of `word` is (it could be an object too). Assigning to it will never update the array.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why doesn't this work?

    function capitalizeLetters(str) {
         let words = str.split(' ');
         words.map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
         return words.join(' ');
    }

Comment: @user3744279 same basic problem: `words.map()` **returns a new array**. You have to assign that new array back to the variable `words`.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet can update your 'words' array. Hope that is what you were looking for.

```
function capitalizeLetters(str) {
    let words = str.split(' ');
i=0;
    for(var word of words){     
        words[i] = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        i++;
     }
    return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalizeLetters('i love javascript'));
```

Comment: I was able to do that using the traditional for loop (with the index i and stuff like that).
However, when I reference those individual words with the 'word' variable in the for-of loop, it doesn't behave in the same way. 
I am looking for an explanation for this difference in behavior.

Pardon me if I haven't phrased the question properly.